# PHP / MySQL — Checking to see if a user is regular or admin

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check if a user is a regular user or an admin.

In my database, the last item is "usertype" and it is a 0 or 1.

0 for regular user and 1 for admin user.

For some reason this is not working. It always tells me I am a "regular user." Which I know cannot be true. I did set usertype as an int to 1.

Here is my admin.php page

```
<?php
include_once '../includes/db_connect.php';
include_once '../includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>


    <?php
        // Create connection
        $con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM members");

        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    ?>




    <?php
        if ($row["usertype"] == 1) 
        {
            echo "You're an admin!";
        } 

        else 
        {
            echo "You're a regular user.";
        }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show sample data from the database and do a `print_r($row);` and show the results in your question

Comment: What's the usertype of the first row, because that's all you're retrieving.

Comment: You guys have this under control. ;-) I'm now retired.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have more than one user in your database? Because `"SELECT * FROM members"` isn't selecting any specific member.

You should really be supplying a username to select from the database like so `"SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$username'"`

Otherwise, check what you're storing usertype as (varchar/int/etc) and make sure you're comparing correctly.

Comment: I deleted my comment about OP to use a WHERE clause. Figured someone would use it. +1 I'm done with answering. Cheers

Comment: Worth noting that the `$username` should be in a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your PHP code. I condensed it & combined it:

```
<?php
    // Create connection
    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM members");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

    if ($row["usertype"] == 1) {
        echo "You're an admin!";
    } 
    else {
        echo "You're a regular user.";
    }
?>
```

Your query does not specify a user.  It just blankly gets all values from `members`:

```
SELECT * FROM members
```

Then you run this:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
```

Which basically means it makes no matter if you have 1,2,3 or even 300 entries in `members`, you will always be grabbing the first result of `members` and acting on that. You need to alter your query to check for a specific username from the table `members`.

Also, for the field `usertype` do you have `1` or `0` set in your database as the number `1` or `0`?  Or is it a string value of `1` or `0`? That too can cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I think that I will need WHERE clause in the query for contrasting the data against the form fields you want to check. For example, If i want the users to log in, using email address and password, I will use the code like this:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM members
WHERE (email = '$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p'))";
```

in which,

```
$e = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $_POST['email']); and $p = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $_POST['password']);
```

And SHA() is to decrypt the password that you might use in your registration process.

So, the next steps are that:

1/ You should check if you the usertype for admin username is 1 or not. I sometimes forget this too :-(
2/ You should replace your if ($row["usertype"] == 1) {...}else{...} with

```
if ($_SESSION['usertype'] == 1) {

echo "You're an admin!";    
}else{ ...}
```